# What are Sql Browser with foreign key / references support?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, foreign-keys, utility

I now want to create foreign keys for all of my mew DBs. So far i have been using sqlite and MyIasm DBs so i havent used a DB that supported it. I am thinking i should install and use a MySql server with InnoDb (connected via C#).

My question is what can i use to actually see the FKs relations? I would like to see it by using a sqlite db if possible. Is there good browser that will let me see all or some of the relationship between tables and columns?

-edit- there can be multiple correct answers so i'll change this into a wiki.

Comment: you want to see foreign key relations with a SQLite DB that does not support foreig keys?

Answer (score 0):

**[Navicat for MySQL](http://www.navicat.com/)** is an excellent MySQL GUI.  It provides everything you mentioned (except the confusing part about SQLite + foreign keys), and is very fast and easy to work with.